# Why data provider in a different class, it needs to be a static method

Tags: java, testng

I have dataprovider in different class and accessing it is different testng class. I observed that if i am not using "static" for returning it throwing error.
I want to know what is the logic behind this.
Kindly help me on this.

Sample Code:

**Error code:**

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] testSumInput() {
return new Object[][] { { 5, 5 }, { 10, 10 }, { 20, 20 } };
}
```

**Correct Code:**

```
@DataProvider
public static Object[][] testSumInput() {
return new Object[][] { { 5, 5 }, { 10, 10 }, { 20, 20 } };
}
```

**Creating Data Provider:**

```
@DataProvider(name="dpProjectDetails")
    public static Object[][] supplyProjectDetails(){
        int noOfRows=CommonMethods.getRowCount(CommonMethods.XLPATH_PROJECT_DETAILS, CommonMethods.SHEET_PROJECT_DETAILS);
        int noOfCell=CommonMethods.getCellCount(CommonMethods.XLPATH_PROJECT_DETAILS, CommonMethods.SHEET_PROJECT_DETAILS);
        Object[][] projectDetails=new Object[noOfRows][noOfCell];


        for(int row=1;row<=noOfRows;row++){
            for(int cell=0;cell<noOfCell;cell++){
                projectDetails[row-1][cell]=CommonMethods.getExcelData(CommonMethods.XLPATH_PROJECT_DETAILS, CommonMethods.SHEET_PROJECT_DETAILS, row, cell);
            }
        }

        return projectDetails;
    }

}
```

**-->Accessing it:**

```
@Test(dataProvider="DPCustomerData", dataProviderClass=TDCreateCustomer.class)
    public void createNewCustomer(String customerName,String custdescription){
        TDCreateCustomer tdCreateCustomer=new TDCreateCustomer();
        POCreateCustomer poCreateCustomer=new POCreateCustomer();

        tdCreateCustomer.setCustomerName(customerName);
        tdCreateCustomer.setDescription(custdescription);

        poCreateCustomer.createNewCustomer(tdCreateCustomer);
    }
```

Comment: I didnt see any change in the error code and correct code..Please update your code samples

Comment: Sorry.., Now updated it..

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are trying to access it incorrectly. You should never try to access it directly, but rather should make the variables non-static and private and should access them indirectly via non-static public methods and then calling the methods on an instance of the class.

In other words most of your problem is in code you've not shown us -- code where you try to "access" the data.

Comment: Thanks...,
My Code for accessing is mentioned in the above question. Please refer it. Also in official site of TestNG they mentioned like 
-->"By default, the data provider will be looked for in the current test class or one of its base classes. If you want to put your data provider in a different class, it needs to be a static method and you specify the class where it can be found in the dataProviderClass attribute"

Comment: The answer is unrelated to TS's question.

Answer (score 0):

To access the method of another class either one have to create a object of class or static method can be accessed directly via ClassName.methodName, it is easy to get the method of another class if it is static. In this approach no need to create the object of you whole class, method can assessed directly for only same purpose

Answer (score 0):

Both answers doesn't seem completely satisfactory to me ).

1) TestNG obviously relies on Reflection there. So I do not think that "ClassName.methodName" really happens there.

2) Yet, it's indeed much simpler to access the public static method of the class than accessing non-static method. The latter requires an instance of that class to be created first. And when talking about Reflection, it could be quite tricky to create an instance of arbitrary class.

3) After all, the general unit-testing concept (if I get it right) is that test cases should be reproducible. Thus they should not (in most cases) depend on instance variables, and static dataProviders are very natural from this point of view.

4) Just to mention: When dataProvider resides in the same class that means that TestNG already has an instance at hand, so it's ok to have it non-static.

Answer (score 0):

Thought of updating the answer based on the current implementation of TestNG.

For data providers in a different class, static method **is NOT compulsory**. The TestNG documentation mentions that :

> By default, the data provider will be looked for in the current test
> class or one of its base classes. If you want to put your data
> provider in a different class, it needs to be a static method ***or a
> class with a non-arg constructor***, and you specify the class where it
> can be found in the dataProviderClass attribute.

So the dataprovider method, if it is in another class, then it need to be static only if the data provider class doesn't have default constructor.

ex:

The below two would work:

```
public class MyDataProvider{
   // Java adds a no-arg constructor if there are no other constructors. Hence this works.
   @DataProvider
   public Object[][] dataSet1(){
      return new Object[][]{{1,"a"},{2,"b"}};
   }
```

and

```
public class MyDataProvider{

   public MyDataProvider(int a, String x){
      // do something.
   }

   // static method. Hence this works even though no-args constructor doesn't exist.
   @DataProvider
   public static Object[][] dataSet1(){
      return new Object[][]{{1,"a"},{2,"b"}};
   }
```

But the below code will not work as there is no no-args constructor and the data provider method is not static. So, TestNG is not able to

1. instantiate the data provider class object
2. or invoke the data provider method in a static way.

```
public class MyDataProvider{

   public MyDataProvider(int a, String x){
      // do something.
   }
   @DataProvider
   public Object[][] dataSet1(){
      return new Object[][]{{1,"a"},{2,"b"}};
   }
```